# How do I remove a specific element from a json use Objectnode?

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

I want remove some value in from json.
the json format is like this:

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0.0135,
    "cnt": 40,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1545598800,
            "main": {
                "temp": 267.03,
                "temp_min": 258.629,
                "temp_max": 267.03,
                "pressure": 741.31,
                "sea_level": 1034.85,
                "grnd_level": 741.31,
                "humidity": 72,
                "temp_kf": 8.4
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 800,
                    "main": "Clear",
                    "description": "clear sky",
                    "icon": "01n"
                }
            ]
}
```

I want remove some data from json .
How can i remove id , icon in weather?
I try this :

```
(ObjectNode) rootNode.get("list").get(i).get("weather")).remove("id");
```

but its not correct and this error happen:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `rootNode.get("list").get(i).get("weather")` will return the `weather` array

```
"weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01n"
            }
        ]
```

Then get the first ObjectNode and remove `id`

```
(ObjectNode) rootNode.get("list").get(i).get("weather").get(0).remove("id");
```

Comment: change the secend get(i) to get(0) then its completely correct.                                                            thank U

Comment: yes, but what if you have multiple `ObjectNode's` in array, in that case i mentioned `get(i)` @alpha_boy

Comment: How can i add field at main like temp_morning?

Comment: Get the 'list' and in that get first jsonnode, in that get 'main' jsonnode, and add

Comment: i did but it replace it with all field and then main has just one field .

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it may work. First convert the JsonNode to ObjectNode

```
JsonNode yourJsonNode;
List<String> fieldsTobeRemoved = Arrays.asList("a","b");
if (!yourJsonNode.isMissingNode() && yourJsonNode instanceof ObjectNode && null != fieldsTobeRemoved) {
    ObjectNode yourObjectNode = (ObjectNode) yourJsonNode;
    fieldsToBeRemoved.forEach(field -> yourObjectNode.remove(field));
}
```